# What does "Etc" mean in time zone definitions?

Tags: timezone

What does "Etc" mean in time zone definitions?

Example: [PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)'s

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT');
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The zone identifiers starting with "Etc/..." come from TZDB-repository maintained by Paul Eggert and hosted by IANA. There is following private non-official github-based repository (labelled as experimental but can be considered as preparing repository for TZDB): github.com/eggert/tz

There you will find an [etcetera-file](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/etcetera). The zone identifiers mentioned above are available in this file. So the answer is:

**"Etc" stands for "et cetera" (latin for "and so forth").**

About the motivation of such naming, I think it is best to directly ask the maintainer of TZDB-repository Paul Eggert on the IANA-mailing-list.

Comment: Meno, thank you for enlightening me. This information is far from trivial. I especially love it when a human being knows more about something than Google does (and in this case more than Stack Exchange as well, it seems). Here's to you!

Comment: @Parapluie Note that Etc/...-zones are fixed offsets where the sign is opposite to what is standard. For example: Etc/GMT+05 means UTC-05. I find this definition quite confusing and always try to avoid these zone identifiers completely. In my programming language Java, I can simply use offset parameters like "UTC-05:00", so in Java no need for using Etc/...-ids.

Comment: Yes, my understanding is that Etc/ exists chiefly for backwards-compatibility of the tz database.